# maximal subgroup of a cyclic group in Dummit

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

In Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page65 exercise16(c), there is a proposition "If $G=\langle x\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n\geq1$ then a subgroup $H$ is maximal if and only if $H=\langle x^p\rangle$ for some prime $p$ dividing $n$ ."

But I find that for a composite $k$ not dividing $n$ , $\langle x^k\rangle$ may be also maximal although $k$ is neither prime nor divding $n$ .

For instance, let $G=\langle x\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $10$ ,then $|\langle x^6\rangle|=\frac{10}{\gcd(6,10)}=5$ implies that $\langle x^6\rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ since there does not exist a composite $c$ s.t. $|\langle x^6\rangle|=5c=10=|\langle x\rangle|$ .

So whether this propositon is correct? Or if we should restrict $k$ to be the smallest integer in $\langle x^k\rangle$ ?

Comment: The keyword is *some*, i.e. $\exists.$ $H$ is maximal iff there *exists* a prime $p$ dividing $n$ s.t. $H=\langle x^p\rangle.$ The generators $H$ are then all the $x^{pm}$'s with $m\in[1,n/p)$ coprime to $n/p,$ so you are right: $p$ is the smallest of such exponents $pm.$ In your example, $p=2$ and $m=1,2,3,4.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characterizing maximal subgroups of cyclic groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294159/characterising-maximal-subgroups-of-cyclic-groups)

Comment: Oh, I get your point. The notion "for some" connects with the fact that $\langle x^6\rangle$ and $\langle x^2\rangle$ are equivalant when $n=10$ . Thank you! And your link also does help.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that both your example and the proposition in Dummit and Foote are correct. Note that in your example, $\langle x^6\rangle$ can also be written as $\langle x^2\rangle$ (i.e. $x^2$ and $x^6$ generate the same subgroup).

Comment: Xiexie! The word "for some" plays a important role in the proposition but I ignore it just now.